# Running time of algorithm in worst case

Tags: algorithm

What's the running time of the following algorithm in the worst-case, assuming that it takes a constant time c1 to do a comparison and another constant time c2 to swap two elements?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > array [j+1])
        {
            swap(array[j], array[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get 2+4n^2. How I calculate it (starting from the inner loop):

The inner loop runs (n-1) times. 

The first time it runs, there is the initialisation of j and the comparison of j with (n-1) to know whether to enter the loop. This gives 2 instructions.

Each time it runs, there is the comparison of j with (n-1) to know whether to continue the loop, the increment of j, the array comparison and the swapping. This gives 4 instructions which run (n-1) times, therefore 4(n-1) instructions.
The inner loop thus contains 2+4(n-1) instructions.

The outer loop runs n times.

The first time the outer loop runs, there is the initialisation of i and the comparison of i with n. This gives 2 instructions.

Each time it runs, there is the comparison of i with n, the increment of i and the inner loop. This gives (2+(2+4(n-1)))n instructions.

Altogether, there are 2+(2+(2+4(n-1)))n instructions, which gives 2+4n^2.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to account for the addition of `j+1` for the index in the if statement and the swap call, and the `n-1` calculation in the inner for loop will be an extra instruction.

Remember, every calculation counts as an instruction, which means that essentially every operator in your code adds an instruction, not just the comparisons, function calls, and loop control stuff.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)               //(1 + 1) + n(1 + 1 + innerCost)          (init+comp) + numLoops(comp+inc+innerCost)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)       //(1 + 2) + (n-1)(1 + 1 + 1 + inner)      (init+comp) + numLoops(sub+comp+inc+innerCost)
    {
        if (array[j] > array [j+1])       //1 + 1        (1 for comparison, 1 for +)
        {
            swap(array[j], array[j+1]);   //1 + 1        (1 for function call, 1 for +)
        }
    }
}
```

runtime = `(1+1) + n(1+1+ (1+2)+(n-1)(1+1+1+ (1+1 + 1+1)))`

runtime = `2   + n( 2  +  3  +(n-1)(  3 +    2  +  2))`

runtime = `2   + n(    5     +(n-1)(7))`

runtime = `2   + n( 5 + 7n - 7)`

runtime = `2 + n(7n-2)`

runtime = `2 + 7n^2 - 2n` = `7n^2 - 2n + 2`

Comment: I forgot to add that the question says to "assume that it takes a constant time c1 to do a comparison and another constant time c2 to swap two elements". Does that not mean that I should count the if statement and the swap call as just 1 instruction each?

Comment: @Phantom You are already assuming it takes one operation to do the comparison and the function call, but in order to do them, you need to calculate what it actually is you are comparing and passing. That is where the extra operations come from.

Comment: @Phantom It sounds like instead of assuming them to be 1, you should have `c1` and `c2` in the your runtime expression. I'm not guaranteeing that this is exactly what your (assumedly homework) question means or is asking for, but this is the way I interpret it.